# How to say 'if ALL Instances of a CSS Class are Removed' in an if/else inside of a foreach Method

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble removing the CSS 'active_bg' class of the wheel's core circle when it's removed from all segments.

The full code is on Github and Codepen.

- Codepen: https://codepen.io/Rburrage/pen/xmqJoO
- Github: https://github.com/RBurrage/wheel

In my click event, I tried saying that if the class exists on a segment, add it to the core circle, too -- ELSE -- remove it from the core circle. My code is within a forEach method that loops through all groups in the SVG.

The part in question is in the last event listener below (the 'click' event).

```
var secondGroups = document.querySelectorAll('.sols-and-mods');

secondGroups.forEach(function (secondGroup) {
    let solution = secondGroup.childNodes[1];
    let module = secondGroup.childNodes[3];
    let core = document.querySelector('.core_background');

    secondGroup.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        solution.classList.add('hovered_bg');
        module.classList.add('hovered_bg');
    })
    secondGroup.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
        solution.classList.remove('hovered_bg');
        module.classList.remove('hovered_bg');
    })

    secondGroup.addEventListener('click', () => {
        solution.classList.toggle('active_bg');
        module.classList.toggle('active_bg');

        if (solution.classList.contains('active_bg')) {
            core.classList.add('active_bg');
            solution.classList.remove('hovered_bg');
            module.classList.remove('hovered_bg');
        }else{
            core.classList.remove('active_bg');
        }
    })

})
```

When the user clicks on a segment of the wheel, the CSS 'active_bg' class gets added to both the clicked segment and the wheel's core circle.

I want to remove the 'active_bg' class from the wheel's core circle but only when it is removed from ALL segments.

Currently, as soon as I remove the class from any ONE segment, it gets removed from the core circle.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Put a loop in your click listener that counts how many of the solutions have the `active_bg` class. Only remove it from the core if the number is 0. Alternatively, keep a global variable that counts how many solutions are active, and remove the class when the count changes to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explained

Okay, so to keep this as short and simply as possible, I changed your logic only ever so slightly, I've just included a check to see if there's at least one option selected, if not, then the core circle has the default class, otherwise, it will continue to have the class name of `active_bg`.

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9wLnafq6/) that I've made.

If there's any further issues with this solution, don't hesitate to ask.

### Edit

I just thought I'd go ahead an include the JavaScript that I was playing around with.

```
window.onload = function() {
  TweenMax.staggerFrom('.solution', .5, {
    opacity: 0,
    delay: 0.25
  }, 0.1);
  TweenMax.staggerFrom('.module', .5, {
    opacity: 0,
    delay: 0.5
  }, 0.1);
}


var secondGroups = document.querySelectorAll('.sols-and-mods');

secondGroups.forEach(function(secondGroup) {
  let solution = secondGroup.childNodes[1];
  let module = secondGroup.childNodes[3];
  let core = document.querySelector('.core_background');

  secondGroup.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    solution.classList.add('hovered_bg');
    module.classList.add('hovered_bg');
  })
  secondGroup.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    solution.classList.remove('hovered_bg');
    module.classList.remove('hovered_bg');
  })

  secondGroup.addEventListener('click', () => {
    solution.classList.toggle('active_bg');
    module.classList.toggle('active_bg');

    if (solution.classList.contains('active_bg')) {
      core.classList.add('active_bg');
      solution.classList.remove('hovered_bg');
      module.classList.remove('hovered_bg');
    }

    // Added this line. 
    if (document.querySelector(".sols-and-mods .active_bg") == null) {
      core.classList.remove('active_bg');
    }
  })
})
```